# How do I make a mail which alerts a few other mails when I send a mail to that one

Tags: list, email, gmail, mailing-list

I tried to make a mail id such as **groupchat2021@gmail.com** which when sent a mail to alerts a few other mail IDs

It is available for my university where when they send a mail to **be2018a@mecha.siu.edu.in** the people who are part of that group are all notified.

I wish to do this because I am now forming an team in my uni and I don't want to create a label and type it every time. Instead anyone who sends a mail to the **groupchat2021@gmail.com** everyone added to that conversation should be notified

Please help me out

Thanks in advance.

P.S my organization uses gmail

Comment: Have you heard of [Discord](https://discord.com/)? Emails are not for chatting. If your organization uses Gmail, you can definitely benefit from Gchat. Gchat is a feature that can be enabled in Gmail.

Comment: @suchislife the thing is, i used the name as an example, but it must be formal. it if for a real organization. i just said groupchat cause i couldn't think of another name.

Comment: If you want to collaborate with people in the organization in real time, use a Discord chat and send an invite to each member you wish to add. Really simple and very powerful. You can further restrict it to Invite Only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I used google groups and it worked
Justsearch for google groups